# Loading data from Spark Structured Streaming into ArrayList

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I need to send data from Kafka to Kinesis Firehose. I am processing Kafka data using Spark Structured Streaming. I am not sure how to process the dataset of streaming query into an `ArrayList` variable - say, `recordList` - of e.g. 100 records (could be any other value)  and then call Firehose API's `putRecordBatch(recordList)` to put the records into Firehose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to check out [Foreach and ForeachBatch](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch) depending on your Spark Version. ForeachBatch comes in V2.4.0 and foreach is available < V2.4.0. If there is no streaming sink implementation available for Kinesis Firehouse then you should make your own implementation of the **ForeachWriter**. Databricks has some nice [examples](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/structured-streaming-etl-kafka.html) of using foreach to create the custom writers.

I haven't ever used Kinesis but here is an example of what your custom sink might look like.

```
case class MyConfigInfo(info1: String, info2: String)

class  KinesisSink(configInfo: MyConfigInfo) extends ForeachWriter[(String, String)] {
  val kinesisProducer = _

  def open(partitionId: Long,version: Long): Boolean = {
    kinesisProducer = //set up the kinesis producer using MyConfigInfo
      true
  }

  def process(value: (String, String)): Unit = {
    //ask kinesisProducer to send data
  }

  def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
    //close the kinesis producer
  }
}
```

if you're using that AWS kinesisfirehose API you might do something like this

```
case class MyConfigInfo(info1: String, info2: String)

class  KinesisSink(configInfo: MyConfigInfo) extends ForeachWriter[(String, String)] {
  val firehoseClient = _
  val req = putRecordBatchRequest = new PutRecordBatchRequest()
  val records = 0
  val recordLimit = //maybe you need to set this? 

  def open(partitionId: Long,version: Long): Boolean = {
    firehoseClient = //set up the firehose client using MyConfigInfo
      true
  }

  def process(value: (String, String)): Unit = {
    //ask fireHose client to send data or batch the request
    val record: Record = //create Record out of value
    req.setRecords(record)
    records = records + 1
    if(records >= recordLimit) {
      firehoseClient.putRecordBatch(req)
      records = 0
    }
  }

  def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
    //close the firehose client
    //or instead you could put the batch request to the firehose client here but i'm not sure if that's good practice
  }
}
```

Then you'd use it as such

```
val writer = new KinesisSink(configuration)
val query =
  streamingSelectDF
    .writeStream
    .foreach(writer)
    .outputMode("update")
    .trigger(ProcessingTime("25 seconds"))
    .start()
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. I was able to implement it. But I am putting one record at a time since this is at the thread level.I used putRecord instead of putRecordBatch

Comment: I edited the code with another example that might help a little more. Maybe you can use batch request in the way I showed.

Comment: Thanks again. Only issue I see with this is to handle the records which are more than recordLimit.  For example say the recordLimit is 50 and you got 55 records. Which part of your code will push the last 5 records to Firehose using firehoseClient.putRecordBatch(req) ? Is there a way to know the end is reached ?

Comment: could you just loop through each record and add it to a batch until recordLimit, send that batch, and then keep creating new batches until you've gone through all records?

Comment: Alex, What changes would be required if Kafka is SSL encrypted ? Thx

Comment: That's a good question I've never set one up other than from the command line client. Though in the CLI client I'd reference a keystore/truststore so I'm thinking it would be similar for a java/scala API client.